# Есть ли возможность замены строк в PDF файле средствами PHP?

Tags: php, pdf

Есть необходимость генерировать сертификаты для пользователей, они будут отправляться им на почту после определенной процедуры. Сертификаты в смысле файл с именем пользователя и некоторым текстом, чтобы потом иметь возможность его просмотреть или распечатать и повесить на стенку.

Проще: администратор загружает pdf файл-шаблон с текстом который нужно, например, **заменить %Username% на Иван Иванович Иванов**.
Скрипт проходит, и меняет необходимые значения.

Comment: Можно. Но для этого вам нужно распарсить pdf вначале. Который не является  идеальным форматом для этого, заменить плейсхолдеры и сформировать новый pdf. Возможны потери и искажения в конечном файле. Зависит от сложности исходного файла. Посмотрите в сторону библиотек для этого pdfparser, htmltopdf, mpdf или если есть возможность реализовать это через COM OpenOffice

Comment: Дело осложнилось тем что в тех pdf используется куча шрифтов и разномастных объектов, распарсить его даже Illustrator нормально не смог, что уж говорить об остальном.
Я думаю зайти с другого конца, в связи с этим вопрос: можно ли не распаршивая pdf наложить сверху блок с текстом в определенном месте и определенного размера?

Comment: Сохраните как картинку и по координатам накладывайте уже что угодно. А вообще правильней всего будет сделать на сайте редактор сертификатов и не привязываться к сторонним файлам

Comment: Картинка будет достаточно больших размеров так как файлы сертификатов должны быть предусмотрены для печати, поэтому и предпочтителен формат pdf.

Редактор сертификатов это замечательно, но в реализации мешают два слова: бюджет и дедлайн, поэтому необходим вариант генерировать файлы по загруженным шаблонам.

Задал вопрос ниже, есть ли возможность наложить поверх исходного pdf (никак не трогая его структуру чтобы не поломать) добавить в определенных координатах определенные текстовые блоки?

Comment: "Не трогая" это скорее всего нет((
А вот слой добавить вроде как можно
https://github.com/Distrotech/PDFlib-Lite/blob/master/bind/pdflib/php/starter_layer.php

Comment: Поделитесь ссылкой на файл который не удаётся сконвертировать. Для примера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно в вашем случае будет удобнее *создать шаблон pdf* документа с помощью php, генерировать его на сервере.

Можете воспользоватся библиотекой **FPDF**.

[Официальная документация](http://www.fpdf.org/)

Ее функционала должно хватить для создания достаточно сложного шаблона, пример как выглядит ее код:

```
require('fpdf.php');
class PDF extends FPDF
{
function Header()
{
$this->Image('logo.png',10,8,33);
$this->SetFont('Helvetica','B',15);
$this->SetXY(50, 10);
$this->Cell(0,10,'This is a header',1,0,'C');
}
function Footer()
{
$this->SetXY(100,-15);
$this->SetFont('Helvetica','I',10);
$this->Write (5, 'This is a footer');
}
}
$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Output('example2.pdf','D');
```

Так-же есть **PDFLib** - но она платная.

Вот пример кода который позволяет положить картинку на бэкграунд и наложить нужную надпись:

```
$name = "Vasilyy Popov";
$pdf ="";
$pdf=new FPDF('P', 'pt', array(<PageHeight>, <PageWidth>));
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('background-image.jpg', 0, 0, <ImageHeight>, <ImageWidth>);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 23);
$pdf->Text(<TextPositionFromLeft>, <TextPositionFromTop>, $name); 
$pdf->Output('pdfSert.pdf','D');
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky спасибо, отредактировал ответ. Подробнее в данном случае не получится)

Comment: Проблема в том что нужна возможность загружать разные шаблоны сертификатов, то есть дизайн меняется постоянно и для каждого случая. 
Есть ли возможность в FPDF загрузить готовый шаблон как, так скажем фон, в котором предусмотрены пустые места, к примеру, а сверху теми же средствами наложить текстовые блоки? То есть с исходным шаблонам работаем просто как с подложкой, а поверху ставим текстовые блоки?

Comment: @AndrewVieru Да, такой вариант подходит, проверил - ответ отредактировал с куском подходящего вам кода. Все что в **<>** замените на нужные значения.

Comment: В предлагаемом вами варианте выходит что все на фоне будет растровым, если это единственный вариант добавления текста в pdf макет то сводит ценность формата pdf к нулю, в таком случае, возможно, проще наверно будет использовать GD и jpeg фон? Примеры сертификатов можно посмотреть по ссылке выше в комментариях.

Comment: @Andrew Да *растровым*. По поводу сводит ценность к нулю вопрос спорный, **преимуществом остается то что на печати ничего не сползет и качество будет то которым вы его сделали** - от куда бы это не печаталось. Если по большому счету для печати сертификата А4 вполне хватит нормального изображения, если будет его разрешение **300dpi** то можно и на больший формат растянуть без заметных артефактов. Но я не полностью знаю вашу задачу по этому как лучше не могу посоветовать)

Comment: А кириллица поддерживается этой библиотекой? На деле оказалось что не очень-то.

Comment: @Andrew Подключите UFPDF - то-же самое поддерживющее utf или-же сконвертируйте и подключите нужный шрифт в ср-1251 ссылка: https://www.jelu.ru/post/generaciya-pdf-sredstvami-php-fpdf-i-kirillica.html